# How to draw the domain of integration in R^3 by using geogebra

Tags: geogebra

We consider the following domain of $\mathbb{R}^3$:

$$D={(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^2; 1\leq x^2+z^2\leq 4, 0\leq y\leq z+1}.$$

How can I draw this region by using geogebra?

I tried to use geogebra but it was difficult for me to draw this region.